# Getting Updates from Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying top use parse.com for an app but I need the information in the phone to update when something changes in the server. is there a way to do continuous checks or for the server to let the phone know when some change has been done in the server? I checked all their documentation but I couldn't find anything

Thanks

Comment: "continuous checks" careful... battery drain.

Comment: you just use PubNub for this, but note that Parse no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

IFAIK, you can implement it by using [ScheduledExecutorService](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

By using ScheduledExecutorService, you can get update from server every X second(s).

Here is an example,

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    //Codes that check update from server
  }
}, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

This will check update from server every 1 minute.

To stop checking update,

```
scheduleTaskExecutor.shutdown();
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: this is completely wrong.  **polling is not a solution** in software engineering.

Comment: It may not be the preferred solution, but it can be a solution depending on the problem you have. Sometimes polling is the best option available. Though I would say that you should avoid polling anytime you can.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution could be to use push notifications to notify the app that there has been a change on the server, and trigger a pull to update everything in the app. It really depends a lot on what kind of data you are dealing with, how often it is going to update, and how quickly the user need to know that there has been a change.

Comment: Also, You could look at GCM Network Manager, https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager to schedule one off vs repeating task. This is better than using fixed Alarm to kick off a job as it has some optimizations built in, such as only run on wifi, when charging etc.

Comment: You can't realistically use Push as a hack if (for some reason) you wanted to avoid using an ordinary, modern, presence system.  (Note too that, if for some incredible reason you wanted to do that -- say, to show off how good you are at doing push! -- it would be mindbogglingly more work.  It's all done in one line of code with Firebase, PubNub, etc.  It's inconceivable you would struggle using Push.)

Comment: First of all, it's really not that hard to get a push and respond to it by updating your app. Second, it is entirely conceviable that someone wouldn't be interested in integrating with whole service just for this purpose. We don't really know his needs. Depending on the use case, push notifications could be a really easy way to handle it.

Comment: You know, I'm afraid that is really pretty wrong, Eagle dude!  (1) it's incredibly simple to use PubNub (or the others) for this purpose - it's why they exist.  (2) if (for some reason) you wanted to try doing this using Push, it is a huge, huge tedious effort. any old company like us have done it any number of times in the "old days" when that was an in-between measure compared to having your own dedicated realtime server (or using SmartFox, etc, in the game situation).  (3) Push just isn't reliable, and there's huge latency.  I'm not sure what to say, it's just "totally standard" today.

Comment: Okay, if those aren't good enough reasons, here is another. It can get expensive fairly quickly. It's just not a reasonable thing to say that everyone should use those services regardless of their needs.